# prepared selection shows blank page

Tags: php, mysqli, prepare

I just set up the prepared query selection but it seems like it does not work.. It shows blank page instead of the content it should show..where is problem?

```
<?php 

        $servername = "";
        $username = "";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT configured FROM members WHERE username = ?');
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($username);

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {

                                if($row['configured'] == ""){
        if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {  


?>
```

With this code I want to check if user has configured his settings and so if yes, then if he is logged in. But the page shows nothing even though I have there everything correct after that code I posted...

Comment: Blank page, a.k.a. *white screen of death*: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: A: You're using the wrong variable in your query.

Comment: @Fred-ii- which one ?

Comment: See my answer below Steven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `$conn` to connect with, then `$mysqli` in your prepare statement.

This

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare
```

Which should read as

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare
```

Also make sure you've started the session.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Check for errors:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

and you have 3 missing closing braces in your posted code.

- I see you're using `$username = "";` in your DB connection and then using the same variable to bind with.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: @StevenTomko Add error reporting to the top of file and see what gives. How is `$username` being defined? From a form?

Comment: @StevenTomko You also have 3 missing braces. If that isn't your full code, please post it.

Comment: the braces are at the end of php after html... now It's fixed cause I didnt notice that I don't have defined $username as you mentioned.. I totally forgot about that... I renamed the $username (in connection) and set the $username = $_SESSION['username']; and now it's working! Thank you for your remind :)

Comment: @StevenTomko You're welcome Steven and it's something that I did edit my answer with, before seeing what you posted above in your comment. Glad to hear it was resolved; *cheers*